# How to fetch all data from table in mysql database in react application

Tags: mysql, reactjs, search

I want to fetch at least 10 user data from MySQL db because I want to add search functionality in my React JS how I fetch at least 10 user data at a time when user scroll it load more data.
Thanks in advance
Db is Structure is something like this

```
table>user
email:varchar100
pass:varchar100
email:varchar100
```

and

```
table>userProfile
displayname:varchar100
profilepic
phonenumber
userType
```

There are two types of user signup first is VIP and second is non-vip when Vip signup then userType will be VIP and when non-Vip signup so it should be non-Vip so I want non-Vip search VIP user both user data push on same table user and userProfile.

Comment: This question needs more information on what backend you are currently using, any request libraries you are using, and what you have tried so far. Currently, the question is too vague to be answered.

Comment: Iam using express

Answer (score 1):

So first of all, React is not made to handle your backend. As I see in the comments, you're using express as a webserver, so I guess it's NodeJS based.

The first thing you have to do is create a route in your backend that will fetch the data from your table. I recommend using REST or GraphQL to do so.

Once your route is set and ready to go (you can test it with tools like Postman), you can then make an HTTP Request from your React app (using fetch or axios as an example) to your backend server, and tada !

Comment: Sofiane iam using graphql but at a time when user login it fetch login data but i want fetch all data of user  there are two tables in my db one is user in user there are two columns email and pass and other table is userprofile so in user profile there are username location usertype. There are two types of user first one is VIP and other one is non-Vip.Non-vip search vip  user because both of data goes in same table but the difference is when non-vip signup then usertype in userprofile is non-vip and when vip  signup so it is vip so please guide me i'm new in mysql and graphql